# Apache Ant builds differently for copied project in different directory

Tags: java, ant

I'm in my project folder with the build.xml. I run `ant` and it builds correctly.

Then I copy this folder to the Desktop in which I run `ant` again. 
Unfortunately the compiler throws an error about some `unreported exception Exception`.

What's happening here? How can I prevent that. Is ant caching something?

thanks!

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing the contents of your build.xml. It's possible that there are hard coded paths that point to nonexistent locations after the project is moved.

Comment: I just checked that again -- that is not the case.